# Service not starting - null object Reference

Tags: android, exception, service

I tried to convert one part of my App to a service, because it needs to run in background. Now a button should start and stop the service, when clicked:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_aim_start);
    tThis = this;
    calc.init();
    status = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.statusView);
    output = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.lbl_output);
    final Intent intent = new Intent(this, AIMService.class);
    startButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.start_aim);
    startButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener (){
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (!func) {
                func = true;
                startButton.setText("Stop AIM");
                status.setText("AIM-Started");
                tThis.startService(intent); //I read somewhere that it would need a 
                                            //context, but it didn't work
            } else {
                func = false;
                startButton.setText("Start AIM");
                tThis.stopService(intent);
            }
        }
    });
```

Now, however, I am getting the following Error:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
       Process: com.protonmail.fabian.schneider.aim, PID: 6081
       java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start service com.protonmail.fabian.schneider.aim.AIMService@1dacca22 with Intent { cmp=com.protonmail.fabian.schneider.aim/.AIMService }: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.os.Message android.app.IntentService$ServiceHandler.obtainMessage()' on a null object reference
       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleServiceArgs(ActivityThread.java:3336)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2200(ActivityThread.java:177)
       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1530)
        t android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5912)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1405)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1200)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.os.Message android.app.IntentService$ServiceHandler.obtainMessage()' on a null object reference
```

The Service is declared in the manifest.
The Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.protonmail.fabian.schneider.aim">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".AIM_start"
                    android:label="AIM"
                    android:configChanges = "orientation"
                    android:screenOrientation="portrait">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <service android:name=".AIMService" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

The Service:

public class AIMService  extends IntentService {

```
private SoundPool soundPool;
private AudioManager audioManager;
private static final int max_streams = 1;
private static final int streamType = AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC;
boolean loaded;
public static String strengthArr[] = new String[4];

static {
    strengthArr[0] = "90,110,90,110";
    strengthArr[1] = "50,89,111,150";
    strengthArr[2] = "0,49,151,200";
    strengthArr[3] = "-50,-1,201,-250";
}

static String downURL = "http://services.swpc.noaa.gov/text/goes-magnetometer-primary.txt";
static String errPatt = "-1.00e+05";

private float volume;

private int strengthSound[] = new int[5];

@Override
public void onCreate(){

    System.out.println("started audio initialization");
    //AUDIO
    audioManager = (AudioManager) getSystemService(AUDIO_SERVICE);
    float currentVolumeIndex = (float) audioManager.getStreamVolume(streamType);
    float maxVolumeIndex = (float) audioManager.getStreamMaxVolume(streamType);
    this.volume = currentVolumeIndex/maxVolumeIndex;
    //this.setVolumeControlStream(streamType);


    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21) {
        AudioAttributes audioAttrib = new AudioAttributes.Builder()
                .setUsage(AudioAttributes.USAGE_GAME)
                .setContentType(AudioAttributes.CONTENT_TYPE_SONIFICATION)
                .build();
        SoundPool.Builder builder = new SoundPool.Builder();
        builder.setAudioAttributes(audioAttrib).setMaxStreams(max_streams);
        this.soundPool = builder.build();
    } else{
        this.soundPool = new SoundPool(max_streams, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 0);
    }
    //Sound pool load complete
    this.soundPool.setOnLoadCompleteListener(new SoundPool.OnLoadCompleteListener() {
        @Override
        public void onLoadComplete(SoundPool soundPool, int sampleId, int status) {
            loaded = true;
            System.out.println("finished loading resources");
            //publishProgress("finished loading resources");
            //SoundPool.Builder(new SoundPool.Builder()).play(strengthSound[0],volume,volume,1,0,1f);
            /*MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.strength0);
            MediaPlayer mediaPlayer2 = MediaPlayer.create()
            mediaPlayer.start();*/
        }
    });
    System.out.println("starting tone init");
    this.strengthSound[0] = this.soundPool.load(this, R.raw.strength0,1);
    this.strengthSound[1] = this.soundPool.load(this, R.raw.strength1,1);
    this.strengthSound[2] = this.soundPool.load(this, R.raw.strength2,1);
    this.strengthSound[3] = this.soundPool.load(this, R.raw.strength3,1);
    this.strengthSound[4] = this.soundPool.load(this, R.raw.strength4,1);
    System.out.println("fin tone init");
}


public AIMService(){
    super("AIMService");
}
@Override
protected void onHandleIntent (Intent intent) {
    //WORK

    while (true) {

        System.out.println("before publishProgress Update");
        //publishProgress("Calculation Started");

        AIMService.dataImport dI;
        try {
            dI = new AIMService.dataImport(downURL);
            String calcData;
            calcData = dI.download();

            System.out.println(calcData);
            AIMService.preAnalysis pA;
            pA = new AIMService.preAnalysis(calcData);
            boolean dateOk;
            dateOk = pA.preanalyse();
            if (dateOk) {
                System.out.println("Data Date is okay");
                //call last line downloader
                dI = new AIMService.dataImport(downURL);
                String lastLine;
                lastLine = dI.downloadLast();
                if (!lastLine.contains(errPatt)) {
                    //data is ok
                    System.out.println("Current data is okay");
                    System.out.println("Current data: " + lastLine);
                    System.out.println("Starting analysis");

                    AIMService.analyse an = new AIMService.analyse(lastLine);
                    int strength;
                    strength = an.analyseData();
                    if (strength != -1) {
                        System.out.println("Strength: " + strength);
                        //outputText(Integer.toString(strength));
                        publishProgress(Integer.toString(strength));
                        //return Integer.toString(strength);


                    } else {
                        System.out.println("Strength not found");
                        //send signal for out of scope to output
                        publishProgress("-1");
                        //return "-1";
                    }
                } else {
                    System.out.println("Current data is not okay");
                    publishProgress("Current data is not okay");
                    //send signal for satellite down to output
                    publishProgress("-1");
                    //return "-1";
                }

            } else {
                System.out.println("Data Date not okay");
                publishProgress("Data Date not okay");
                //send signal for satellite down to output
                publishProgress("-1");
                //return "-1";
            }


            //catch statements
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            System.out.println("MalformedUrlException for dI allocation");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("IOException in dI alloc");

            //check inet conn/send satellite down to output
            return;
        }
        //return "ERROR";
    }
}
```

What have I done wrong?

Comment: can you post the manifest

Comment: I added the manifest to the question

Comment: ok post the Service as well

Comment: Yes, you'll get that error, because at time when listener i setOnLoadCompleteListener() fires, Service will terminate

Comment: so I just have to remove the oncomplete listener?

Comment: No, change IntentService to Service

Comment: ok thx.. I will try that....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just for completion of the topic; here is a summary of the answer:

Like Alex Shutov told me, I changed the Intent Service to a service.
I accomplished that by following the official documentation:
[Documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html)

For all interested in the code and/or the project:
[GitHub AIM](https://github.com/faeblDevelopment/AIM.git)

Answer (score 1):

You use IntentService, it creates a separate Thread to execute task in command and then it terminates right after it. You should do all work in onHandleIntent(Intent intent) method.
In your case use ordinary Service, not IntentService.

Comment: In my service there is a onCreate that does some small stuff... And the main work is done within the onHandleIntent(Intent intent) - I don't see my mistake...

Comment: there is no point of stopping IntentService, it will stop authomatically once work is done

Comment: the service is a never ending calculation that generates tones that are sent to the audio output. 
so i thought stopping the service would be a good idea, if someone gets bored by the noises =P